# Free fall and gravitational time dilation

Tags: general-relativity, time-dilation, free-fall

An observer *A* at rest in a gravitational field has some amount of time dilation relative to an observer *B* far away from the gravitational field.  Would the clock of an observer *C* in free fall at the same location as *A* be dilated relative to *B*s clock exactly the same as observer *A*s clock *(i.e. at a given location in a gravitational field, does the amount of time dilation at that location depend on whether the observer is at rest or in free fall)?*
Does a free falling observers clock become increasingly dilated relative to a clock at rest at infinity as it falls in a gravitational field *(in addition to any time dilation effects due to relative velocity)?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be no effect at all at t=0.
When t grows, the object will gain spatial speed, and this will contribute to an almost negligible time dilation. The greater effect (at least near a planet or stsr and not a black hole) will be an increasing gravitational time dilation as the object falls deeper into the gravitational potential.

So the answer to your first question is a rotund «No.» and to the second «Yes.»

You can read my article «Sistemas en caída libre y,corrimiento hacia el azul gravitacional» ( Spanish - «Free falling systems and gravitational blueshift ), Lumen, September - October 1993.